# Precise meaning of "vanishes to first, second, etc. order"

Tags: real-analysis

If a real valued function $f(h)$ is $o(|h|)$ for $h \to 0$, meaning that

$$\lim\limits_{\substack{h \to 0}} \frac{f(h)}{|h|} = 0,$$

do we say that $f$ "vanishes to first order", or that it "vanishes to second order"? In case my interpretation of the wording "vanishes to $n$-th order" is completely wrong, what is the precise meaning?

PS: I believe that here we would have to say that f "vanishes to first order", and in the case of $o(h^2)$ f would vanish to second order, etc. At least I seem to remember that usage from Taylor expansions. But then, to what order does $f(h)=h$ vanish with $h \to 0$? To zero-th order?

Comment: If $n$ is an integer, I think "vanishing to order $n$" means there are constants $c,C>0$ such that $c|x|^n\le |f(x)|\le C|x|^n.$

Comment: This is known as *sublinearity.* If $f(x)/\|x\|^2 \rightarrow 0$, then $f$ is subquadratic, and so on.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{h\to0}$ usually has $h\neq 0$ baked into the definition.

Comment: @zhw. Usually I would leave out the lower bound - and with the lower bound included, I would call that something along the lines of "vanishes strictly to order $n$".  (Only I would probably look for something that sounds less awkward...)